# Iterate through a string and print filtered words

Tags: python

I'm stuck on one of the tasks in my Python course. I also have to use Jupyter notebooks, I don't know if that changes anything.

I need to take an input, iterate through it and separate them into individual words and print them only if the word starts with a letter larger than G. If not, empty the string out and start on the next word.

This is my code:

```py
# setting up the variables
quote = ("Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart")
test_quote = quote.lower()
words = " "
# check is the letter is an alphabet; if it is, add it to the empty string
for character in test_quote:
    if character.isalpha():
        words += character
    else:
        # checks if the letter is greater than h; if it is, print it, if not, add a new line
        if words[0] >= "h":
            print(word.upper())
        else:
            print("\n")
    # reset the string
    word = " "
```

I'm supposed to end with this result:

```
WHERESOEVER
YOU
WITH
YOUR
HEART
```

But I get(Nothing):

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I don't think I'm allowed to use functions like .split(), you're supposed to be able to do this for/in loops, input, if, else, .isalpha(), .upper(), .lower(), .isupper() and .islower().

Comment: It can help a lot if you quickly learn how to debug program code. Update your answer section (is it really empty?).

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variables and information which part of code is executed. It helps to see problem. It is called "print debugging". OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: Hint: How do you initialize `words`? What is `words[0]` immediately after you do that? When you append to `words`, will it change that fact? What will happen, therefore, when you compare `words[0] >= "h"`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
quote = ("Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart")
quote = quote.upper()
quote = quote.replace(",","")
word = ""
for i in quote:
    if not i == " ":
        word += i
    else:
        inWord = word[0]
        if inWord > 'G':
            print(word)
        word = ""
inWord = word[0]
if inWord > 'G':
    print(word)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this print `GO,` as opposed to `GO`?

Answer (score 0):

there are problems between 'word'/ 'words' and where you resetting was not correct. try this one:

```
quote = ("Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart")
test_quote = quote.lower()
words = ""
for character in test_quote:
    if character.isalpha():
        words += character
    else:
        if words.isalpha():
            if words[0]>= "h":
                print(words.upper())
        words = ""

if words.isalpha() and words[0]>= "h":
    print(words.upper())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have one question: why does using "word" as a variable not work? Is there some stored value in the variable "word"?

Also, why is there another .isalpha() and print after the for loop? Sorry if these are stupid questions, I'm quite new to python.

Comment: you have assigned characters in 'words' variable and spaces  in 'word' variable. So, you gets lots of spaces while printing 'word' variable